# Using cURL, can I test if proxy credentials are valid without pinging a random server?

Tags: c++, curl, proxy

I'm developing an application that supports the usage of proxies via .pac files. Some of the proxy servers in the pac file require credentials and I want to prompt the user for credentials when the application tries to access one of these servers and then check if the credentials are ok. The simplest way would be to simply ping a server going through a proxy with those credentials. The problem is that I pinging a random server isn't valid.

Is there any way to check if proxy credentials are valid, using curl, without pinging a random server?

Answer (score 0):

You need a RPC(Remote Procedure Call) server. For example you can use Apache Thrift framework.